# Force Firebase to use cellular connection [iOS]

Tags: ios, firebase, wifi, iot

I'm trying to connect my iOS app to an IoT device via WiFi. Problem is, Firebase (and Crashlytics/Fabric) doesn't understand that there's no internet connection over that WiFi connection and tries to use it anyway, messing up the communication with the device. It tries to check if there's an internet connection available and that sometimes causes delays which cause the IoT device to stop communicating.
Is it possible to explicitly specify Firebase's internet connection and change/update it manually (i.e., when the device is disconnected)?
Maybe I should just drop the Firebase completely since I'm only using it for user login/crash reporting anyway?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe that there is any way to force a connection to use the cellular network. iOS will always use WiFi if it is connected.

Comment: Still, it appears that the Outlook app is able to get emails via LTE when my phone is connected to the IoT device over the WiFi

Comment: I just tested that and it isn't the case for me.  I connected my phone to a WiFi that has no Internet connection and Outlook just shows a "No Internet" message.  It did not receive a test email that I sent, which was received in Outlook on my Mac.

Comment: OK, I see, I'll check that again, might be mixing things up. For the time being, I just disabled data collection by setting **FirebaseDataCollectionDefaultEnabled** flag to **NO** in the `Info.plist` file. seems like right now it's not trying to connect to the Internet anymore.